# Autotest Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autotest

Get the following error when I run autotest. 
The weird thing is that I don't have the folder /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/ but the folder /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.9.1/.

Help? Thanks.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/heroku-2.8.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-07 00:00:00.000000000Z"
loading autotest/rails_rspec2


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/nikeelevet/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/heroku-2.8.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-07 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/heroku-2.8.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-07 00:00:00.000000000Z"
/Users/nikeelevet/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:20: undefined method `desribe' for #<Class:0x1045bff68> (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:142:in `module_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:142:in `subclass'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:129:in `describe'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:5:in `describe'
    from /Users/nikeelevet/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `autorun'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec:4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blonde moment, I was able to remove the gem specified in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try an older release of autotest and/or heroku version to check if this problem is just a bug?

Although that's not your question, I would like to recommend the gem guard to you. Is there any reason to prefer autotest to guard?

https://github.com/guard/guard

Comment: No reason, I just started learning ROR with this tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book that uses autotest.